# Multiple radio buttons rows inside ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, radio-button, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a flow of three div working with each other (and 3 arrays)
The idea is to select some options on the first div (from the first array), those options are passed inside the second one (and the second array).

I have an ng-repeat inside the second div which displays the selected options with, for each one, four radio buttons.

The radio buttons have an ng-click value which will add the option associated to the radio button value to the third array and will allow to sort the options by the different radio buttons checked.

```
DIV1            DIV2                          DIV3
|option1|       |option2|                     radio1 : option2
|option2|       oradio1 oradio2 oradio3       radio3 : option4
|option3|  -->  |option4|               -->
|option4|       oradio1 oradio2 oradio3
```

The problem comes from my radio buttons, I've tried to change their name / values / ng-model change values for ng-values and I can't find a way to make it work.
Either I have all my radio buttons changing at the same time or only on radio button line working at a time or all object having the radio value being updated...

I have an idea of what's going on, my scope is updating everything because my ng-model is the same or values are the same but I can't find a way to make it work...

I have spend my day on it... so it's time to get help :)

Here is a plunker of the code I have (I've made a lot of change like I said) but the idea is here...

http://plnkr.co/edit/jElDW1aUAv3k4cqou54y?p=preview

Thank you !

```
<EDIT>
```

The idea of option may not be very understandable just imagine you have some buttons for people
Mary
Chloe
David
etc.

The radio buttons are team bleu / red / yellow

I select the person I want in the first panel attribute them a team in the second one and display the person per team in the third one :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this can be helpful for you.

I've made a fiddle based on your code.

[Please check this.](https://jsfiddle.net/Canet/x5o8jv4k/4/)

```
$scope.addPerson = function(personName){
    var obj = {};
    obj['name'] = personName;
    $scope.peopleArr.push(obj);
    $scope.personName = '';
};
```

Is this far from your intent?

Comment: Ok I was doing it completely wrong... Today is gonna be a good day, thank you !